# 90 days in USA then to holland for 3 weeks then back to USA for 90 days

Tags: usa

I have been in the US for 90 days and I want to go to holland for 3 weeks. After that I want to return to the US for another 90 days. My question is, can I do this?

Comment: What is your nationality, under what visa or replacement of those do you travel and can you give more details.

Comment: I have the Australian nationality and I am travelling on the Visa Waiver Programm. I still got 1 month left before I need to leave the USA.